# element.id returns HTMLInputElement object

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, attributes

Am debugging one form and found that element.id of this form returns its input element.

```
element => 

<form class=​"form-horizontal editor settings" role=​"form" action=​"#">​…​</form>​

element.id => 

<input type=​"text" name=​"id" value class=​"form-control" data-binding-id=​"547">​
```

I tried to get elements constructor - nothing unusual

```
element.constructor => ƒ HTMLFormElement() { [native code] } 
element.id.constructor => ƒ HTMLInputElement() { [native code] }
```

The question is here - how to create the form like this in JS console?
Even if I create the `<form>` and assign `<input>` element to its id:

```
actualElem.id = document.createElement("INPUT")
<input>​
actualElem.id
"[object HTMLInputElement]"
```

`element.id` would return string, not an `<input>` itself.

Comment: change `name="id"` to something else. (∩ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)⊃━☆ﾟ. * ･ ｡ *magic*

Comment: since an input within the form has a name of `id`, `theform.id` gives you that input element instead of the form's id. you can still use getAttribute to get the form's id. You can recreate this on the console by adding a input to the form that has a name of "id". The same thing happens when you give a button the name or id "submit", thus making it impossible to call `form.submit`